# 2d array with different types of elements and using classes

Tags: c++, arrays, class

Same story as loads of other people here. Very new to c++ (programming in general) and am seriously stuck with an assignment.

I have to create and implement a class for a DVD store. I must also create an array to store info regarding DVD's. The elements of the array must be of type class (that I have to create)

My challenge so far is that the array must contains elements of types int, string. As far as I can tell (lots of Googling) this is not possible.
I get the feeling that it will be possible somehow using classes but I cannot find a way around it.

Please help.

Thanks

Leon

Comment: Same response as loads of other people:  use a 2d array (vector) of structures.  Put your DVD store items into a structre.

Comment: You say that you must create an array where each element is (an instance of) a class. You *do* know how to create a class? And how it can be used as a type? You *do* know how to create an array of a type like `int`? And you know how to create a "2d" array of e.g. `int`? Then you really know all you need to know, just combine your knowledge. Though to be honest I don't see why you want a "2d array"? Just a simple array of your `DVD` class would do.

Comment: The array will not contains elements of type int and string. It will contain elements of type `class DVD` and the class `DVD` will contain ints and strngs.

Answer (score 1):

BTW, you are working on a primitive database, so let's call a DVD store item a *record*.  The idea is to treat things generically as possible until specifics are required.

A DVD store record:

```
struct Record
{
  std::string title;
  std::string artist;
  std::string genre;
  double price;
};
```

Now to create a database to hold all the records:

```
std::vector<Record> database;
```

You may want to create *index tables* to help speed up your searches without having to resort the database each time.

```
std::map<std::string /* Title */, unsigned int /* Index into database */>  Index_By_Title;
std::map<std::string, unsigned int>  Index_By_Artist;
```

This becomes a 2d container because you are accessing the row by using an index into the vector, then you can access the column by using the member name.